# Performance expectations when running caret::train() to develop a kknn model

Tags: performance, classification, cross-validation, r-caret, knn

I'm using the *caret::train()* function to develop a weighted knn classification model (kknn) with 10-fold cross-validation and a *tuneGrid* containing 15 values for *kmax*, one value for *distance*, and 3 values for *kernel*.

That’s 450 total iterations if I understand the process correctly (an iteration being the computation of the probability of a given outcome for a given combination of *kmax*, *distance*, and *kernel*).  *x* has about 480,000 data points (6 predictors each having about 80,000 observations), and *y* has about 80,000 data points.

Understanding that there are innumerable variables affecting performance, how long can I reasonably expect the *train* function to take if run on a pc with an 8-core 3GHz Intel processor and 32GB of RAM?

It currently takes about 70 minutes per fold, which is about 1.5 minutes per iteration. Is this reasonable, or excessive?

This is a kknn learning exercise. I realize there are other types of algorithms that produce better results more efficiently.

Here is the essential code:

```
x <- as.matrix(train_set2[, c("n_launch_angle", "n_launch_speed", "n_spray_angle_Kolp", "n_spray_angle_adj", "n_hp_to_1b", "n_if_alignment")])
y <- train_set2$events
set.seed(1)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, p = 0.8, returnData = TRUE,
                           returnResamp = "all", savePredictions = "all",
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, classProbs = TRUE, 
                           verboseIter = TRUE)
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(kmax = seq(11, 39, 2), 
                        distance = 2, 
                        kernel = c("triangular", "gaussian", "optimal"))
kknn_train <- train(x, y, method = "kknn", 
                    tuneGrid = tuneGrid, trControl = fitControl)
```

Comment: Are you running on Widows, OSX or Linux? Also, why don't you run it in parallel?

Comment: **Edit** Keep in mind, also, that the `tune.grid` runs, for example, `kmax = 11` 10 times, per `kernel`; and this continues. So I dont believe that the 450 iterations are correct.

Comment: It's running on Windows. I guess my question is, should I have to run in parallel? It just doesn't seem that demanding, unless I'm misunderstanding what's going on behind the scenes, which is what you seem to be suggesting when you say kmax = 11 causes 10 iterations per kernel. I'm not sure I understand that. While the documentation defines kmax as the maximum number of neighbors, kmax can also be used to specify a range or sequence of specific k values. Thus, the tuneGrid created by my code has 45 rows (entries) listing the 45 possible combinations of parameters per fold.

Comment: First of all, Windows is slow by definition unless you use a spaceship and components from another planet where Windows works ok with R. In any case, regardless of the combinations, you could try to slowly scale your data. Start with 1/10th and see how long it takes. It is quite a conputation, and it should be done in parallel if you ask me!

Comment: Serkan, thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Would parallel processing make a difference if total cpu usage reaches only 55% while running the above caret::train() function on Windows 10?

Comment: I  am by no means an expert in computers. However, I have been doing quite some machine learning. And it is my understanding that CPU usage depends on how heavy the calculations are; and if you use, say, 4 cores then you will definetly get a gain; and notice that I dont say all cores, as Id expect that with only 55% the overhead costs could be larger so you would suffer diminishing returns.

Comment: What are your run times with multiple cores so far? And have you ever considered using Linux? Personally, I have always used OSX, and upgraded to a much larger windows desktop. I literally spent 30 mins on it, and decided to use Linux instead; and I havent been more satisfied on this matter. Linux is terrible to use in the beginning, but once you get used to it, it is awesome for Machine Learning.

Comment: How about uploading your data, then we can compare run times. Or we can find a dataset, and run some algorithms and compare that way. Im running on 32 gb ram i7 8th gen.

Comment: Here's the link to the data. You already have the code. Curious to see what happens. You have the same processor and RAM as me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAiuSMy3eVKoOA10hs0ow48VXcuPYzb-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok - I've downloaded your data. But I doubt it is the same processor though, I have 12 cores. Ill run single core, and max 8 cores this evening. Going to be a blast. :-) **Edit** Its a 12 core i7-8700T with 2.4 GHZ.

Comment: Ok James, Ive run it so far since the morning. And I am currently at Fold 6; there is a total of 920 iterations, it runs each `kmax` twice pr `kernel`. And `KNN` in itself is quite heavy, and with `6x80.0000` rows, this kind of behavior is to be expected. When I do this kind of work, I take a small random sample from the data and find the best parameters, and run the final model on that. It has worked like a charm for me; and it will give an unbiased measure of your best parameters.

Comment: Also, your calculations are pro-longed by adding `returnData = TRUE` as an example, this is redundant as you already have your data. I, personally, suspect that `caret` reruns and resaves the parameters inside the `trainControl`-parameters which increases run time.

Comment: Serkan, thanks so much. That's very helpful. And I learned something new.

Comment: So, just to be clear, how long is it taking per fold? And you are not running parallel, correct?

Comment: The Intel Core i7-8700T @ 2.40GHz actually has six cores (12 threads), but our processors are comparable enough that we'll be able to see if running parallel makes a significant difference. Also, those 920 iterations you thought you saw when it was on fold 6 was really 460 iterations because it shows both the start and the end of an iteration. It's not running each kmax twice per kernel, only once.

Comment: I've also tried running it with returnData = FALSE, but it didn't make any difference. It's still taking 70 minutes per fold.

Comment: OK - Here are my run time; 80.4 minutes per fold. Which, considering your single core is 1.25 better than mine, is 7-10 minutes faster alone because of running on Linux. I am going to be honest, I did not know that it showed the start and end of the iteration. I learned something there (I usaully run without `verbose`). I have not run it in parallel; I guess Ill do that sometime tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, I wasnt just referring to `returnData`, but also `returnResamp` and `savePredictions`. Granted, this is miniscule but nevertheless affects RAM.

Comment: In any case; I think it should be clear now that it is reasonable to expect this kind of run time. On an honest side-note, I didnt really grasp the 80k rows, before I actually loaded the data. If I realized this earlier, my answer would have been 'yes' right away. Personally, running in small samples first, and then upscaling is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: AND just ditching Windows altogether. Its terrible. Plain as that.

Comment: Serkan, thanks for your efforts. I'm really curious to see whether running it with parallel processing makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As we have established in the comments, it ***is*** reasonable to expect this type of runtime. There are a few step to reduce this;

1. Running your code in `parallel`
2. Using a more efficient OS; like `Linux`
3. Be more efficient in your `trainControl()`, is it really necessary to have `returnResamps=TRUE`? There is small gains in controlling these.

Clearly, the first one is a no-brainer. For the second one, I can find as many computer-engineers who swears to `linux` as those who swears to `windows`. What convinced me to switch to `Linux`, was this particular test, which I hope will give you what it gave me.

```
# Calculate distance matrix
test_data <- function(dim, num, seed = 1903) {
    
    set.seed(seed)
    
    dist(
        matrix(
            rnorm(dim * num), nrow = num
        )
    )
    
    
    
}


# Benchmarking
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test_data(120,4500))
```

This piece of code simply just runs faster on the exact same machine that runs `Linux`. At least this was my experience.

Comment: Serkan, thanks for your suggestions. I will try them. At this point, I don't think we've established that running the code in parallel will make a significant difference, since neither of us have actually done this. I will try it.

Comment: As for Linux, again, I don't think we've established that using Linux instead of Windows will make a significant difference in this case. When you tried running the code on Linux, you actually had longer run times than I did, with comparable system resources.

Comment: How so? You have 3 Ghz and I have 2.4 ghz - so clearly I will have longer run time! Or what did I miss here?

Comment: Running this is in parallel ***will*** help.... but for the sale of argument, I will run it this evening. On all cores - just because...

Comment: OK - So, I started the model now. However, RAM usage is slowly climbing so I highly doubt it will finish in the morrow. If it crashes during the night Ill remove the redundant arguments in `trainControl()` and rerun tomorrow evening again.

Comment: I've already tried running it after modifying the trainControl arguments as follows:

Comment: fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, 
                           returnData = FALSE, returnResamp = "none", 
                           savePredictions = "none",
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, classProbs = TRUE, 
                           verboseIter = TRUE)

Comment: It made absolutely no difference. Still at 70 minutes per fold. I need the class probabilities because I apply custom criteria for evaluating performance at various decision thresholds.

Comment: No difference? o.0 And you are certain you ran it in parallel? I dont see `allowParallel = TRUE` in your `trainControl()`!

Comment: No, I did not run in parallel. Just removed all the "redundant" or unnecessary arguments that I could.

Comment: Did you notice any difference in RAM usage? Because the main benefit of removing these are there, and for applications with many iterations. Anyhow, Ive run it in parallel and I got 14.6 minutes pr. fold.

Comment: Wow! That's excellent. I'll give it a try. Thanks for all your help. How many cores did you end up using?

Comment: Still trying to get parallel multi-core processing to work in Windows. It seemingly finishes running at the 2 hour and 15 minute mark with all the correct computations -about one-fifth the time it takes running non-parallel. But when my subsequent code runs, it keeps running in an infinite loop. Here's the code:                                                                                                `library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 6)

kknn_train <- train(x, y, method = "kknn", 
                    tuneGrid = tuneGrid, trControl = fitControl)

stopImplicitCluster()

Comment: What do you mean "infinite loop"? Im not sure what to make of your comment really.  Can you please update your post with your attempt to parallelize and eventual errors? Im not familiar with Parallel'ing on Windows. I just know it sucks... :0)

Comment: I was able to use 6 physical cores for parallel processing of the caret::train() function with 10-fold cross validation. This was to build an optimized weighted knn model. Without parallel processing, the function took 660 minutes to run. With parallel processing, the function took 135 minutes to complete. I did experience one troubling side-effect following parallel processing (this was the first time I had ever done it). I have thousands more lines of code to run after this instance of the train function completes. However many lines of subsequent code I select to run... cont'd

Comment: However many lines of subsequent code I select to run, RStudio shows a random number of those lines repeatedly being processed over and over again. The contents of the Global Environment pane are refreshed/rewritten every 10 to 30 seconds. At the same times, the repeating lines of code continue to be added in the Console pane, one after another, always the same lines. I haven't been able to resolve.

Comment: It's almost as if the system continues to attempt to perform parallel processing on the subsequent code, much of which isn't suitable for parallel processing. But I'm speculating there.

Comment: Hmm - If you closed your parallel connection this shouldnt be an issue at all; and if the code doesnt have a parallel backend R wont run it in parallel. That is for sure. We spent alot of time on this question - do us all a favor, and try to migrate your codes to Linux and see how it goes. Otherwise post another question, and lets fix your issue!